# Access fields in a template of components inside components inside components

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I've a problem here. The structure that I have at the moment is:

```
ComponentA
   FieldA1 - textField
   CombonentsB - componentLink (multi-value)
       FieldB1 - textField
       ComponentC - componentLink
           FieldC1 - textField
```

Now I am trying to place ComponentA with Template on a page.
I am using DWT Templating.
What I need is to access FieldC1 in the template.

I've already added the "Add Linked Components To Package" TBB in TemplateA.
I think it is identical to this one:
http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/addcompstopackage.aspx
I can access FieldB1 in my template but not the fields further down in the hierarchy.

Do I have to write another TBB that includes the whole hiearchy, or should it work as expected and my access code is just wrong?

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="ComponentsB" -->
@@ComponentC.Fields.FieldC1@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

What can I do to make it work? Are there any other solutions then writing a new TBB?

=========== SOLUTION ============

After Nickoli Roussakov told me about the DGX, I managed to implement it correctly.
Here the code:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="ComponentsB" -->
    @@Get("ComponentsB[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Fields.ComponentC.Fields.FieldC1")@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GetLinkedComponents works only on the first level of component nesting because you can't go deeper than that with DWT syntax.  Your options are to write a custom tbb that renders out the output needed down from componentB, or try Nuno's DGX extension (also on sdltridionworld) instead of GetLinkedComponents.

Comment: thx a lot, I managed to implement the requirement with the DGX!